# How to configure SonarQube6.2 to use https?

Tags: https, sonarqube, ssl-certificate

I have SonarQube 6.2 installed and and want to configure it to use https. All instructions I have seen thus far, regarding this, suggest that 5.2 seems the last version to support https. Does SonarQube 6.2 support https? The instructions I'm referring to can be found here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Running+SonarQube+Over+HTTPS

If https is supported in 6.2 - I have not been able to find any instructions in the installation instructions.

Answer (score 9):

In 5.4 the native support for HTTPS was dropped. See the [5.4 Upgrade notes](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Release+5.4+Upgrade+Notes).

As replacement they now advise to use a reverse proxy (as stated in the upgrade notes). The current docs (6.3) are [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Securing+the+Server+Behind+a+Proxy) and explain on how to use either Apache, Nginx or IIS as the reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.